# More than one htmlspecialchars string in PHP MySQL

Tags: php

I have a table in MySQL where there is a row with this data.

- id = 187
- friendly name = i don't like mustard
- filetype = exe

This first block of code below works perfectly, and echos text **i don't like mustard** into an HTML form.  Similarly, if I change `$row['friendlyname']` to `$row['filetype']`, text **exe** is echoed.  All good, no issues yet.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('domain','user','pass','db');
$sql = "select * from installers where id=187";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
$friendlyname = htmlspecialchars(" ".$row['friendlyname']." ",ENT_QUOTES);

$con->close();
?>

<input type='text' value='<?php echo $friendlyname; ?>'>
```

The problem I'm having is if I try to echo both `$row['friendlyname']` and `$row['filetype']`, only the variable that is listed first will be echoed.  For example, in the below code, `$row['friendlyname']` is listed before `$row['filetype']`.  In this example, only `$row['friendlyname']` (**i don't like mustard**) will be echoed.  Similarly, if `$row['filetype']` is listed before `$row['friendlyname']`, then only `$row['filetype']` (**exe**) is echoed, and the second other HTML input form is empty.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('domain','user','pass','db');
$sql = "select * from installers where id=187";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
$friendlyname = htmlspecialchars(" ".$row['friendlyname']." ",ENT_QUOTES);
$filetype= htmlspecialchars(" ".$row['filetype']." ",ENT_QUOTES);

$con->close();
?>

<input type='text' value='<?php echo $friendlyname; ?>'>
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $filetype; ?>'>
```

**Note 1**: It doesn't matter the order of the input type forms.  I ruled that out as the issue.
**Note 2**: If I were to replace `$row['friendlyname']` and `$row['filetype']` with the text I'm trying to echo, then it work (the below code).  So, this definitely appears to be something with these $row variables.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('domain','user','pass','db');
$sql = "select * from installers where id=187";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
$friendlyname = i don't like mustard;
$filetype= exe;

$con->close();
?>

<input type='text' value='<?php echo $friendlyname; ?>'>
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $filetype; ?>'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not added brackets into `while` loop so only first record is populated.

This block:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
$friendlyname = htmlspecialchars(" ".$row['friendlyname']." ",ENT_QUOTES);
$filetype= htmlspecialchars(" ".$row['filetype']." ",ENT_QUOTES);
```

Should be:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $friendlyname = htmlspecialchars(" ".$row['friendlyname']." ",ENT_QUOTES);
   $filetype= htmlspecialchars(" ".$row['filetype']." ",ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you!  That resolved the issue.  I'm sorry I'm still kind of new to stackoverflow, so I don't have high enough reputation to  up your response as useful.  Once my reputation is high enough, I'll come back here and up this.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: @JeremyCanfield A few of us have upvoted, however in 16 mins you can accept the answer, which gives emmanuel some rep-based thanks from you

Comment: Thank you so much James!  I really appreciate being welcomed to the community.  I will definitely accept Emmanuels answer in 16 minutes (and some others too!).